# Angular 9 - passing data to child component using service - ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm learning Angular and am stuck on passing the data to the child component. I've used a few different methods but keep getting stuck. I have a list on *portfolio.component.ts (parent)* that would ideally route to the *project.component.ts (child)*, passing the data of the clicked item.

**project.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Project } from './project.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class ProjectService {

    projects: Project[] = [
        new Project('Acme', 'Acme website description', '/assets/img/kitten.jpg', 'acme tag', 'acme', 'acmemfgco.com'),
        new Project('Kyle Whitaker', 'Fort Worth, Texas Attorney', '/assets/img/kyle-whitaker.png', 'kyle w tag', 'kyle-whitaker', 'kwhitaker.com')
    ];

    getProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
        return of(this.projects);
    };
    
}
```

**portfolio.component.ts (parent):**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Project } from './project/project.model';
import { ProjectService } from './project/project.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-portfolio',
  templateUrl: './portfolio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./portfolio.component.scss'],
  providers: [ProjectService]
})
export class PortfolioComponent implements OnInit {
  projects: Project[];

  constructor(private projectService: ProjectService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.projectService.getProjects().subscribe(projects => this.projects = projects);
  }
}
```

**portfolio.component.html:**

```
<div class="container projects">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <a [routerLink]="['project', project.slug ]" *ngFor="let project of projects">
                <div class="project">
                <div class="outside">
                  <div class="inside"><img style="width: 500px;" [src]="project.imagePath" alt="{{ project.name }}" class="project-image img-responsive"/></div>
                </div>
            
                    <div class="{{ project.cssClass }} text">
                        <h2> {{ project.name }} </h2>
                        <p class="project-tag"> {{ project.tag }} </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**project.component.ts (child):**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Project } from './project.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project',
  templateUrl: './project.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project.component.scss']
})
export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() project: Project;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    console.log(this.project); //undefined ?

  }

}
```

**project.component.html:**

```
 <div class="container">
    <h1>{{ project.name }}</h1>
 </div>

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

**app-routing.module.ts (snippet):**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: IndexComponent },
    { path: 'portfolio', component: PortfolioComponent },
    { path: 'portfolio/project/:slug', component: ProjectComponent },
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
    { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using route parameters you can pull out the `slug` from the URL when the project page loads

```
 { path: 'portfolio/project/:slug', component: ProjectComponent },
```

Then you can use your service to filter your projects to find the project that matches the slug, and return the full project to use in your component (e.g. if you had a function called `getProjectBySlug`)

```
export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit {
  project: Project;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const slug = this.route.paramMap.get('slug');
    this.project = this.projectService.getProjectBySlug(slug)
  }
}
```

You can see more examples of this in the [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#route-parameters)

Comment: most welcome! Glad you were able to figure it out